# How to check if a specific SPAN class content text

Tags: javascript, jquery

wanna check whether a specific SPAN class context text or not?
The SPAN class I want to check against is "distance" that has the kilometers numbers like (, 27 kilometers).

Tried the below code but still not working

```js
if ($('.trip-summary-info').find('distance').length > 0) {
  alert("Working !!!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trip-summary-info">
  <h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="back_first">
      <span class="chevron-up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span> Booking Summary: &nbsp;
      <span class="date-time"></span>07-07-2017 09:05<span class="distance">, 99.84 kilometers</span><span class="duration">, 1 hrs 13 mins</span>
    </a>
    <span class="custom-btn custom-btn-default edit back_first"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></span>
  </h3>
  <div class="trip_status custom-clearfix">
    <span class="location-form-marker"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
    <div class="location-form"></div>
    <div class="list-address-point" style="display:unset;"></div>
    <span class="location-to-marker"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
    <div class="location-to"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="additional_seats_wrapper editable-field">
    <strong>Additional Seats: </strong><span id="additional-seats" class="text-muted"></span>
    <!-- overlay-icon -->
    <div class="overlay-icon">
      <a class="btn-icon back_first" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /overlay-icon -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.find('.distance')` , Prefix `.` with class selector

Comment: you've missed the dot before your classname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
var $distance = $('.trip-summary-info .distance');
if ($distance.text() === ""){ 
   // There is no text, so handle that
}
else {
   // There is text, so you could do something different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.` represent the class in `find()`

```js
if ($('.trip-summary-info').find('.distance').length > 0) {
console.log($('.trip-summary-info').find('.distance').text())
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trip-summary-info">
  <h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="back_first">
      <span class="chevron-up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span> Booking Summary: &nbsp;
      <span class="date-time"></span>07-07-2017 09:05<span class="distance">, 99.84 kilometers</span><span class="duration">, 1 hrs 13 mins</span>
    </a>
    <span class="custom-btn custom-btn-default edit back_first"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></span>
  </h3>
  <div class="trip_status custom-clearfix">
    <span class="location-form-marker"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
    <div class="location-form"></div>
    <div class="list-address-point" style="display:unset;"></div>
    <span class="location-to-marker"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
    <div class="location-to"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="additional_seats_wrapper editable-field">
    <strong>Additional Seats: </strong><span id="additional-seats" class="text-muted"></span>
    <!-- overlay-icon -->
    <div class="overlay-icon">
      <a class="btn-icon back_first" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /overlay-icon -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `.` before `distance` to find class.

```html
<div class="trip-summary-info">
      <h3>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="back_first">
       <span class="chevron-up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
       Booking Summary:
       &nbsp;<span class="date-time"></span>07-07-2017 09:05<span class="distance">, 99.84 kilometers</span><span class="duration">, 1 hrs 13 mins</span>
   </a>
   <span class="custom-btn custom-btn-default edit back_first"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></span>
      </h3>
      <div class="trip_status custom-clearfix">
       <span class="location-form-marker"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span><div class="location-form"></div>
       <div class="list-address-point" style="display:unset;"></div>
       <span class="location-to-marker"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span><div class="location-to"></div>
      </div>
      
   
      <div class="additional_seats_wrapper editable-field">
   <strong>Additional Seats: </strong><span id="additional-seats" class="text-muted"></span>
   <!-- overlay-icon -->
   <div class="overlay-icon">
    <a class="btn-icon back_first" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
   </div>
   <!-- /overlay-icon -->
      </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

if($('.trip-summary-info').find('.distance').length > 0){
    alert("Working !!!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through this:

```
if($(".trip-summary-info").find('h3').find('.distance').length > 0){
   alert('working!!').
}
```